# Appium, Mocha, Android, JS - Is it possible to pass settings via command line (like version of android) when run tests?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, mocha.js, appium

I'm very new in mobile testing and I have several problems and questions.

*Problem 1:* I have several real devices on which I run tests. It's a little bit annoying to change Android version in conf file in capabilities every time I switch between devices.

**Question 1:** I want to pass version of Android when I run the test. When I write tests on Jasmine + Protractor, I could configure this in conf file like this:

```
switch (browser.params.env) {
    case 'case1':
      browser.params.url = 'url1';
      break;
    case 'case2':
      browser.params.url = 'url2';
      break;
    }
```

and run tests like this:

```
npm run test -- --browser.params.env=case1
```

Is it possible to do the same in Appium+Mocha? I was trying to use **--default-capabilities** flag, but it's not what I need.

*Problem 2:* I want to set username and password as environment variables (found an example [here](http://docs.bitbar.com/testing/appium/desired-caps/index.html)), but I don't understend how to do it correctly in Appium?
At now users data store in separate file like this:

```
const users = [
  {
    id: 'someId1',
    pass: 'somePass1'
  }
]
```

But I don't think it's a good idea to store pass in tests. So how to use these environment variables?

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create file like `caps.js` in `config` folder to store capabilities matrix:

```
const caps = {}

caps.android6 = {
  platformName: 'Android',
  automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
  deviceName: <device name>,
  appWaitActivity: <activity name>,
  appWaitPackage: <package name>,
  androidInstallTimeout: 90000,
  app: <path to app>
}

caps.android5 = {
  platformName: 'Android',
  platformVersion: '5.0',
  automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
  ...
}

caps.default = {...}


module.exports = caps
```

if you are using `wd.js`, you can create driver following way:

```
const path = require('path')
const caps = require(path.resolve('config','caps'))
const wd = require('wd')
const server = {host: 'localhost', port: 4723}

const capabilities = caps[
  process.env('caps') !== 'undefined'
    ? process.env['caps']
    : 'default'
]
const driver = wd.promiseChainRemote(server)
await driver.init(capabilities)
```

And when you run tests, you can do it like `export caps=android6 && npm run tests`, where `tests` is a script you specified in package.json to run your mocha tests. In this case `android6` data from caps.js is used.

Same approach you can use for providing credentials:

```
export login=user@gmail.com password=124356 && npm run tests
```

and in your tests you can read it via `process.env`

Comment: Hi! Many thanks for your answer. I'm going to try this solution in a few days and will give feedback.

Comment: Thanks, it works! :) The only difference that I changed `process.env('caps')` to `process.env['caps']`. In the case with `()` I received an error that process.env is not a function.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad that I helped you and thanks for comment, I updated answer with correct brackets